# VB.NET Insert DataGridVIew content into SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm having issues inserting data from my datagridview into my SQL Server table

The error I get is this:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The parameterized query '(@Articulo varchar(8000),@Cantidad varchar(8000),@Precio varchar' expects the parameter '@Articulo', which was not supplied.

My code:

```
Private Sub btnGetTotal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetTotal.Click
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("xxx")
    Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Ordenes_Full (Articulo, Cantidad, Precio) VALUES (@Articulo, @Cantidad, @Precio)")
    Dim dataAdapter As New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dataSet As New Data.DataSet

    command.Parameters.Add("@Articulo", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    command.Parameters.Add("@Cantidad", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    command.Parameters.Add("@Precio", SqlDbType.VarChar)

    connection.Open()
    command.Connection = connection

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        command.Parameters(0).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
        command.Parameters(1).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
        command.Parameters(2).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
 
End Sub
```

Comment: For nulls you need `DbNull.Value` so `If(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value, DbNull.Value)` etc. And I strongly advise you to sweep away this code and use `SqlBulkCopy` instead. And what purpose are `dataAdapter` and `dataSet` serving?

Comment: How was the `DataGridView` filled. Was a `DataTable` used as the `DataSource`?

Comment: `The parameterized query '(@Articulo varchar(8000)` This should give you a clue that something is wrong generally. Specify the length of your parameters. Are they **really** varchar at all? Is Cantidad (quantity) numeric? If it is not, should it be numeric? Bad habits are difficult to unlearn.

Comment: You should not be looping like that at all. You should bind a `DataTable` to the grid in the first place, ten use a data adapter to save the data in one go with a call to `Update`. You would set the `InsertCommand` of that data adapter and set the source column for each parameter. That would automatically handle "empty" cells as the `DataTable` would contain `DBNull.Value` in those fields by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing this quite differently, as I suggested in a comment on the question. If you're going to stick with this method though, you have to make sure that "empty" cells are saved to the database as `NULL`. You can do that like this:

```vb
command.Parameters(0).Value = If(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value, DBNull.Value)
```

That will use the `Value` of the cell unless it is `Nothing`, in which case it will use `DBNull.Value` instead.

`DBNull.Value` is what ADO.NET uses to represent a database `NULL`. The reason that it cannot just use `Nothing` for that is because ADO.NET was created in the days before nullable value types. If you used `Nothing` where, for instance, an `Integer` was expected then that would be interpreted as zero rather than `NULL`.